# How do you get filenames and save and display there names in labels. KivyMD Kivy Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to display file names on Kivy Buttons but I want to add a feature so when there is not txt file the Buttons don't show up but the more txt files that you have the more labels you have.

I have a system where you save text to a file a give the file a title so I want the user to know if this file exists. I currently have no knowledge on how to do this. My idea is when you press the button with the file name for example "test" it will display the text of the txt file but I don't know how to display the names of the txt files on the buttons and there might not be any txt files so you would have to hide the buttons. I am using KivyMD so those buttons would be preferred.

Here is a screenshot of the page that the buttons would be displayed on:

[image: The Image]

I hope the experts of python could help me out here.

Update:

```
    files_list = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
    for k in files_list:
        type = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(k)[0]
        if type == "text\plain":
            MainScreen.add_widget(Button(text=k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two screens approach. First screen for list of buttons and second for editing text.

```py
import mimetypes, os
files_list = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
for k in files_list:
    type = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(k)[0])
    if type == "text\plain":
        mylayout.add_widget(Button(text=k))
```

Here `mylayout` is a kivy layout depends upon how you want to arrange your buttons.

For displaying text, second screen would contain a label. Just read the text file and assign it to `text` property of label.

Comment: when a file is created the label is not being created I will update the code

Comment: @GClreland For live creation of labels, you need to run a seperate thread(say twice a second) to check if new files are created

Comment: How do I do this